# Connection refused error with django-elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I'm trying to integrate ElasticSearch with my Django project using the package `django-elasticsearch-dsl`, and I am getting this error:

```
>> $ curl -X GET http://localhost:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

I downloaded `django-elasticsearch-dsl` using the commands:

`pip install https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl/archive/6.4.0.tar.gz`

and

`pip install django-elasticsearch-dsl`, but they both caused the same results.

I don't believe this is a duplicate question because every other question I have read pertaining to this error has dealt with only the ElasticSearch library, not the `django-elasticsearch-dsl` library. The latter is built on top of the former, but I can't seem to find a `elasticsearch.yml` file as detailed in all other posts.

Here is what is installed in my virtual environment:

```
>> pip freeze

Django==2.2.2
django-elasticsearch-dsl==6.4.0
elasticsearch==7.0.2
elasticsearch-dsl==7.0.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.1
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint==2.3.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.1
requests==2.22.0
typed-ast==1.4.0
urllib3==1.25.3
```

According to [this tutorial](https://samulinatri.com/blog/django-elasticsearch/), the command `http://127.0.0.1:9200` should return what looks like a JSON response, but instead I get the error:

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused`

Comment: Check Elasticsearch server is running or not? Also check the port of Elasticsearch.

Comment: @AshwaniShakya That's what I was trying to do was check if the server was running or not, and I would get a connection refused error. I made sure in my django app that the port was 9200.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made documents.py for each app? You need to make it to push the data to the elasticsearch database. But firstly you need to install elasticsearch properly(in your case its not installed properly).

Try this Tutorial for installing elasticsearch, i used it recently and it worked  like a charm.

[Link](https://logz.io/blog/elasticsearch-tutorial/)

And this is the path for elasticsearch.yml, (/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml).

And dont forget to start it using - sudo systemctl start elasticsearch(check its status using - sudo systemctl status elasticsearch )

Comment: Yes I have made documents.py for each app. Also, i'm trying to use `django-elasticsearch-dsl`, do I still follow this tutorial?

Comment: This tutorial is for installing elasticsearch properly, which you require for django-elasticsearch-dsl.So i suggest if you still have error, purge your elasticsearch , read the requirements carefully from the tutorial and then reinstall it.

Comment: I'm using docker to install ES according to the official website, so this tutorial isn't relevant to me